# Best way to display online / offline status in jqmobile web app

Tags: html, user-interface, jquery-mobile

I have a web app built in jquery mobile which works in both online and offline modes depending on whether there is a connection.

My question is purely cosmetic: Is there an established way of communicating to the user which mode is currently being used? eg. Icon in header, colour scheme etc.

Comment: I don't know if there is an established way, but I've been using a a navbar in the footer with one of the *tabs* containing a colored icon (just a dot) and the text online/offline depending on the current status.

Comment: Sounds sensible thanks